# Is a 45 degree turn in the vertical portion of a drain line OK?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, drain

The drain line for my kitchen sink currently drops vertically through the subfloor and makes a 90 degree turn in the joist bay below.

[image: Front view of current location]

I am relocating the sink, pushing it about 20" back, e.g., perpendicularly away from the horizontal run of the drain. In order to keep the vertical drain in the sink cabinet, I would have to make a 45 degree bend below the sanitary tee and then run at that angle through the cabinet base and into the joist bay, and then tie into the horizontal run from there.

[image: Side view of new location]

Would this be allowed by code? Would it lead to clogs?

Comment: Is your drawing profile view or isometric? I.e., is that 45&deg; with respect to horizontal?

Comment: Yes, it is with respect to horizontal (the angle is not to scale).

Comment: Normally that move would be done under the floor, on the horizontal run. Is that an option?

Comment: Do you mean to install a new horizontal run in the next joist bay over? I don't know what issues I would run into trying to tie the new line into the downstream part, as I can't see it.

Comment: For vents, 45 (or more) is defined as vertical. I don't believe that applies to drains.